# How can i set up ngDevMode to true in Angular?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-4

On production I am having this error **JIT compiler unavailable**

I googled a lot for this problem and to get more specific error I found that i need terser webpack plugin inside my webpack configuration to get specific error that is making problems for my JIT compilation.

Here there is explanation about that

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43415

The second comment from stevethemacguy.

But I can't find a way to add this to my `extra.webpack.config.js` file.

**what i did**

I installed `npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev`

I added terser plugin inside my webpack

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    /**
     * Remove all unused MomentJS locales
     * The problem is described in this article
     * https://medium.jonasbandi.net/angular-cli-and-moment-js-a-recipe-for-disaster-and-how-to-fix-it-163a79180173
     */
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /de|en|fr|it/),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: /node_modules/,
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            }
        ]
    },
    "terserOptions": {
        "warnings": true,
        "safari10": true,
        "output": {
            "ecma": 5,
            "comments": false,
            "webkit": true
        },
        "compress": {
            "ecma": 5,
            "pure_getters": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true
            },
            "passes": 3,
            "global_defs": {
                "ngDevMode": false,
                "ngI18nClosureMode": false
            }
        },
        "mangle": true
    }
}
```

now i get error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'terserOptions'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
```

I need to configure this so on production I will get output which dependency is making problems in my angular compilation

I am having the following webpack dependencies inside my angular project

```
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "10.0.1",
 "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
 "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.9.0"
```

**ts config**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "es2020",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true
    }
}
```

**angular json**

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "xecm": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "xecm",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "customWebpackConfig": {
                            "path": "config/extra-webpack.config.js",
                            "mergeStrategies": {
                                "plugins": "prepend"
                            }
                        },
                        "outputPath": "target/dist",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": false,
                        "assets": [
                            { "glob": "favicon.ico", "input": "./src", "output": "/" },
                            { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./src/assets", "output": "assets" }
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/../node_modules/customLib-scss/dist/imports.css",
                            "src/../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "src/../node_modules/customLib-scss/dist/customLib-scss.min.css",
                            "src/styles/main.scss",
                            "./node_modules/xcomponent-angular/widgets/lookup-text-field/lib/theme/lookup-text-field.scss"
                        ],
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": ["src/styles/partials"]
                        },
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
                            "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap.native/dist/bootstrap-native.min.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "baseHref": "/xecm-web/xecm-app/ng2/",
                            "deployUrl": "/xecm-web/xecm-app/ng2/",
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                                    "maximumError": "15mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                                    "maximumError": "10kb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "xecm:build",
                        "proxyConfig": "config/proxy.conf.js"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "xecm:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "xecm:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
                        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "xecm:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "xecm:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "xecm"
}
```

Comment: Why are you using JIT to begin with ? Angular is AOT by default since v12 IIRC

Comment: Please share your angular.json and ts.config

Comment: I will share now, btw i have aot: true but i guess that some third party dependencies that I am using are making problems in the ocmpilation, i read that librraries with compilationMode: 'partia; can cause there problems

Comment: The problem is i thing in this library https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/ng-option-highlight/tsconfig.lib.json So i am using library that internally is using this library - and to be sure that this library makes problems i need to set up the terser webpack plugin in the compilation

Comment: @MehyarSawas please refresh the page, i edited one more time

Comment: @MGX I am using AOT compilation.Please check my angular.json file

Comment: If you want to use terser options then you must follow the schema of webpack config. optimization > minimizer > [new TerserPlugin({terserOptions: {}})]. But just recommend before you use the webpack custom builder, try to upgrade all your libraries in package.json to the latest version and check you app for any use of the compiler.

Comment: @MehyarSawas and check you app for any use of the compiler.  - Could you please explain this part? I did not unerstand

Comment: @MehyarSawas I tried using but i get error - could you please post an answer for the question ?

Comment: @MehyarSawas I don't know how to set up this terser plugin, so the ngDevMode will be true and I will get more specific error in my console

Comment: @MehyarSawas I can't find any terserOptions related to this on webpack documention

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/ checkout this Link

Comment: @MehyarSawas I posted an answer. This has nothing to do with terserOptions  but with webpack plugin. Thank you for the effort !

Comment: If you are using dynamic rendering for your components then probably you are not using the deprecated compiler in your code. But still there might be some libraries   that work with angular and not up to date.

Comment: @MehyarSawas Please check my new question. Provide an answer if you know it...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361440/how-can-i-point-to-specific-folder-in-node-modules-in-my-webpack-config

Answer (score 1):

I found a way

So we need to use webpack definePlugin

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: /node_modules/,
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ngDevMode: true,
        }),
    ],
}
```

After I added this definePlugin inside my webpack config then I got better error pointing to which library was the problem for the JIT compilation